# ServiceStack OrmLite Include Column in Where Clause but Not Select

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Consider the `LoyaltyCard` database DTO I have below:

```
[Alias("customer_ids")]
[CompositeIndex("id_code", "id_number", Unique = true)]
public class LoyaltyCard
{
    [Alias("customer_code")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    [Alias("id_code")]
    public string LoyaltyCardCode { get; set; }

    [Alias("id_number")]
    public string LoyaltyCardNumber { get; set; }

    [Alias("date_issued ")]
    public DateTime? IssueDate { get; set; }

    [Alias("linked_id")]
    public bool LinkedId { get; set; }

    [Alias("positive_id")]
    public bool PositiveId { get; set; }
}
```

I have `CustomerId` as a property because I need it to be included in the `WHERE` clause of the generated SQL, but I don't want the column to also be selected in the result set. Is there a way to include it in the where but exclude it from the select?

```
// I was hoping that result would not have a populated CustomerIds
var result = db.Select<LoyaltyCard>(id => id.LoyaltyCardCode == "PS" && id.CustomerId == customerCode);
```

I've tried adding the `[Ignore]` attribute but that fails with `SqlException: Invalid column name 'CustomerId'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the entire POCO populated you'd need to specify a Custom Select with just the fields you want selected, e.g:

```
var result = db.Select<LoyaltyCard>(db.From<LoyaltyCard>()
   .Where(id => id.LoyaltyCardCode == "PS" && id.CustomerId == customerCode)
   .Select(x => new { 
       x.LoyaltyCardCode,
       x.LoyaltyCardNumber,
       x.IssueDate,
       x.LinkedId,
       x.PositiveId
   }));
```